# Google form responses to existing Google sheet columns and maintain existing formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have an existing [google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1fUFlKfG22UO7nh8TtnM5fRHv84z0l_eYQKSMDjF2xhU/edit?usp=sharing) and am looking to:

[Image 1. of the google form question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgihU.png)

1) Have the response to the question (What is your name) in the form automatically populate (**Sheet 1, Column C**) on this existing [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NEg4erCHWN_4vqdnNbHB8PC-ZJPuRCeL_5viGiAmm-E/edit?usp=sharing)

[Image 2. Where the google form data will have to go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAXlp.png)

2) The timestamp that gets generated with each google form submission to automatically populate (**Sheet 1, Column E**) in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

3) While these google form responses will be recorded in this spreadsheet there will be times when I will have to manually go in and enter information in subsequent rows as well.

Is this possible to do? I am new to bringing in data from google forms into google sheets, can anyone help with the questions above?

Comment: It looks like the form responses are in another sheet in your spreadsheet. You could simply use `={'Form Responses 1'!A2:A}` (or whichever sheet name/column combination the name answer is in) in cell C2. Same with the date. Then you can format the date column.

Comment: Thank you @s1c0j1. If I understand you correctly, I need to use ={'Form Responses 1'!A2:A} as a formula when conditional formatting?                            + Also, isn't there a way not to have to post process the date column by formatting the column everytime a new time stamp is sent from the google form? Is there a way to simply have the time stamp appear in the column as YYYY-MM-DD format. + Second, there will be times when I will have to enter the names myself and sometimes rely on the google form responses.

Comment: There was no mention of conditional formatting. If you set the whole column's format at the beginning, you won't have to change it after each submission. I'll get back to you about the rest.

Comment: Hi @s1c0j1, I did everything as you had listed out but end up getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")" in the script editor when I press the play button.

Comment: You cannot debug in the normal way with an event object. Try submitting a form.

Comment: Thank you @s1c0j1. I submitted the form twice and both the times no responses were recorded in the target spreadsheet. None of the sheets were populated. (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NEg4erCHWN_4vqdnNbHB8PC-ZJPuRCeL_5viGiAmm-E/edit#gid=0) and the error when clicking the play button still persists. The google form link here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGpJ8S8LEOSR8Uy8z5DEc0pLvHedXXgZzuMJOIMMCxlzU9xQ/viewform

Comment: The error when clicking the play button will *always* persist because there is no event passed when running through the script editor. I'll check your sheet soon. :)

Comment: Hi @s1c0j1, I checked back at the spreadsheet this morning and the inputs from the form was populated in the default sheet (i.e., Form Responses 1). But for some reason did not appear in the target sheet (i.e., Sheet 1).

Comment: I also received an email from app-scripts notification that "TypeError: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")". Does this information help, @s1c0j1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. A couple of things.

1. Go to the **Tool** menu > **Script editor**.
2. Name the script (maybe 'Form Submission'?) by clicking the '**untitled project**' text in the top left of the editor.
3. Replace all text in **code.gs** with the code below. (Change the code where indicated).
4. Then go to **Edit** > **Current project's triggers**.
5. Click the link that says: **No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.**
6. Under Run, select **onSubmit**.
7. Under Events, select **on form submit**.
8. Click **save**.
9. Now you should go back to the editor and push the play button. This will run the function and initiate the authorisation process. Click through the prompts and accept.

Now, every time a form is submitted, the name and timestamp will be copied over.

```
function onSubmit() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var responseSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var copyToSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Target');

    var rLastRow = responseSheet.getLastRow();
    var tLastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var lastCol = responseSheet.getLastColumn();

    var values = responseSheet
        .getRange(rLastRow, 1, 1, lastCol)
        .getValues()[0];

    var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(values[0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    var name = values[1];

    copyToSheet.getRange('C' + tLastRow).setValue(name);
    copyToSheet.getRange('E' + tLastRow).setValue(timestamp).setNumberFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

Comment: Hi @s1c0j1 thank you so much for your help thus far. I am hoping that you might have some time this weekend to revisit this again?

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a delay in the responses showing up, sorry. I did rewrite the code though. Try that. :)

Comment: Hi @s1c9j1, the responses now do show up asap on the "Form Responses 1" but when I click the play button for the script I get this error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 5, file "Code")". And the target sheet, "Sheet 1" does not get populated. Any idea what might be going on? Could it be that the target spreadsheet and the sheet within it are both named "Sheet 1"?

Comment: I left the target spreadsheet as "Sheet 1" but changed the target sheet to "Target" but still receive the "TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null. (line 5, file "Code")" error. So the naming of the sheets must not be it.

Comment: Your script is bound to the spreadsheet, yes? It's not unbound or bound to the form?

Comment: Hi @s1c0j, to summarize, when I fill the form after using the updated script that you sent, the "Form Responses 1" sheet (i.e., the default sheet tied to the form) gets filled with the time stamp and the response but the target sheet, where we want to copy the data to does not have any information transferred to.

Comment: I understand. Did you understand my last question?

Comment: Hi @s1c0j1, sorry I totally overlooked your question. If I understand your question correctly, no the spreadsheet is not bound to the form. I just linked them together so it would be easier to see Form responses & Manually filled responses (target sheet) together in one spreadsheet. If that answers your question?

Comment: I am asking if the **script** is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes perfect sense. Yes the script is a bound script to the form and not the spreadsheet. Here is what I did. I opened the form >> tools (i.e., 3 vertical dots) >> script editor >> copied and pasted your script >>... etc. Shall I make it bound to the spreadsheet instead?

Comment: Please bind it to the spreadsheet instead. :) That is the issue. Then set up a trigger for on form submit. :)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @s1c0j1. Let me try that on my end and will let you know what comes of it.

Comment: Hi @s1c0j1, we are getting a lot closer. :) I now see information added to the target sheet. But the date is not showing up correctly. Instead of 1/12/2019, the date that gets shown is "1969-12-31". Second, the name (response to the question) only gets populated in the "Form Responses 1" sheet but not the "Target" sheet. Also, the date is not being filled in the subsequent row but a few rows down.

Comment: Drum roll please... Have updated the code. I made a stupid mistake when using `getRange()`.

Comment: Soo excited!!! Thank you @s1c0j1! Let me give it a go and see where it lands me. Will let you know..

Comment: Yesss!!! It gets the data in the "Target" Sheet as expected. Now is it possible for the responses to fill the next available row? Cause as of right now, there are 7 or 8 empty rows above that are empty and the responses are populating from Row 10 onwards. The reason why I ask is because the "Target" sheet will not only have responses from the form but also manual entries sometimes.

Comment: Thank you @s1c0j1. Unfortunately that didn't do the trick just yet. I deleted all the responses from the form (in the form, and in the spreadsheet) to start with a clean slate. But when I fill the form, the response gets lodged in Row 14 of "Form Responses 1" sheet and subsequently gets lodged in the same row (Row 14) of "Target" sheet, even though there are a lot of rows empty above.

Comment: I've corrected it so it won't keep writing to the same row. It will always add to the row after the last data occurs. If you delete the empty rows in your target sheet and update the code (I added `+ 1`) it *should* be good.

Comment: We're sooo close. I am so thankful @s1c0j1. It looks like the responses are not being lodged in the pre-formatted rows in the "Target" spreadsheet. Even though there is no data in Rows 3, 4 and 5, the data ends up in Row 6 instead. Does this mean that I cannot have a pre-formatted Target sheet?

Comment: But there is data in those rows. They aren't empty. You should post another question as we're now off-topic from your original question. :)

Comment: Ah will do. Thank you @s1c0j1. I am new here let me figure out how I can upvote your solution to my original question. Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: Done! I really appreciate your help and the time you devoted to my query. Thank you @s1c0j1. Have a good night!

Comment: You too! I will look for your next question. :)